# Replacing factors that are only dependent on a single specific variable

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, coefficients

I have expressions with terms that are products of factors. Some of the factors are expressions that depend on a single specific variable. I would like to replace those factors with constants and create a separate list with the replaced constants. An example:

```
(L Myb)/EIy + (L Myb Rzc^2 (12 + la^2 - 6 la Coth[la/2]))/(12 GJ la^2)
```

This example only has two terms. The second term has the factor

```
(12 + la^2 - 6 la Coth[la/2])/la^2
```

that is a function of `la`. I would like to replace all factors that only depend on `la` with constants, so turning the expression into

```
(L Myb)/EIy + c1 (L Myb Rzc^2)/(12 GJ)
```

and into a list

```
c1 -> (12 + la^2 - 6 la Coth[la/2])/la^2
```

How can I do this? In particular, I am struggling to match "any complicated" function of `la`.